# mod_proxy returns blank page for rails 3.1 app with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger, mod-proxy

this is driving me nuts and I'm trying to get this running since days so maybe I'm a little bit focused on the wrong topic but here are the results of my investigations:

1. I have an apache2+passenger running with sever applications (php + rails)
2. I've installed rvm to use different gemsets and (main reason) to use ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9.2 depending on the application --> this works perfect!

okay, now I wanted to display those applications and I found out, that I have to setup passenger in a different way. good news: old applications work (1.8.7) new application (1.9.2) does not. so I did...

1. install mod_proxy to route request to an passenger server running on 127.0.0.1:3000 --> also good news: this works

BUT....

even the logfiles of the rails application shows, that the applications is rendered without any errors on every request, the page only displays a doctype.

more strange: when I had an configuration error on my Gemfile, the correct passenger error was show.

So I'm a little bit stuck here.

my mod proxy configuration is pretty basic:

```
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    #turning ProxyRequests on and allowing proxying from all may allow
    #spammers to use your proxy to send email.

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            AddDefaultCharset off
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Proxy>

    # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
    # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
    # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block

    ProxyVia On
    </IfModule>
```

virtual host:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.host.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public

    PassengerEnabled off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    <Directory /var/www/myapp>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

if you need any further information to help me resolving this issue please let me know!

thank you for ANY hint :/

/edit/
funfact: header is serving "Server:nginx/1.0.6 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.9 (mod_rails/mod_rack)" although no nginx is installed on this server...